# Garland sub-theme color functionality is not working

Tags: 7, theming

I have a subtheme in Drupal 7 for Garland theme. below is my my_garland.info file for the sub-theme

```
name = My Custom Sub Theme
description = Custom sub-theme of Garland
core = 7.x
base theme = garland
stylesheets[all][] = my_garland.css
```

i have also include some information in the template.php file to help with the color module

```
function my_garland_process_html(&$vars) {
  // Hook into color.module.
  if (module_exists('color')) {
    _color_html_alter($vars);
  }
}
```

I have also copied the color and images file from the garland theme therefore the initial blue works perfectly and i can see the color wheel but the total page layout is not changing.
I have also tried to follow [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/466268) link to see if it will be resolved but all in vain. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

From [Example: Creating a Garland Subtheme That Utilizes the Color Module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1969060)

> That said, even if you do not have a style.css file in your subtheme
>   directory, you still must add it to your .info file with
>   stylesheets[all][] = style.css

Comment: Thanks @J.Reynolds, but as you are aware if I add style.css to the info file, this will override the style.css from the main theme. hence the whole site will be without the style.css attributes.